# Center subfigures of different heights

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, subfig, raise

I'm trying to center two subfigures that have different heights, but I can't seem to be able to allign them.

The original code is like this, and the subfigures are aligned at the bottom

```
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Users collection.]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Images/Database_users.png}\label{fig:database:subfig1}}%
\qquad
\subfloat[Events collection.]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Images/Database_events.png}\label{fig:database:subfig2}}%
\centering
\caption{Database Architecture}
\label{fig:database}
\end{figure}
```

I tried the suggestions from the package documentation, but the right side caption alligns to the right, and the figures are overflowing into the rest of the document overlaping the text:

```
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{figure}
\sbox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Images/Database_users.png}}
\subfloat[Users collection.]{\usebox{\tempbox}\label{fig:database:subfig1}}%
\qquad
\subfloat[Events collection]{\vbox to \ht\tempbox{%
\vfil
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Images/Database_events.png}
\vfil}\label{fig:database:subfig2}}%
\caption{database}\label{fig:database}
\end{figure}
```

I also tried using \raisebox but the raised figure just disappears from the document:

```
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Users collection.]{\raisebox{0.5em}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Images/Database_users.png}\label{fig:database:subfig1}}%
\qquad
\subfloat[Events collection.]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Images/Database_events.png}\label{fig:database:subfig2}}%
\centering
\caption{Database Architecture}
\label{fig:database}
\end{figure}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a `\raisebox{-.5\height}{}` will center the graphic about the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Users collection.]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=30pt,width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \label{fig:database:subfig1}}%
\qquad
\subfloat[Events collection.]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=50pt,width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \label{fig:database:subfig2}}%
\centering
\caption{Database Architecture}
\label{fig:database}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also need the captions aligned, then, add a `\rule` the height of the tallest image to the other figure(s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Users collection.]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=30pt,width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \label{fig:database:subfig1}\rule[-25pt]{0pt}{50pt}}%
\qquad
\subfloat[Events collection.]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=50pt,width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \label{fig:database:subfig2}}%
\centering
\caption{Database Architecture}
\label{fig:database}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! As a follow-up question to the \rule command: instead of using absolute values (-x) is there a relative way of doing it so it matches the other subfigure?

Comment: @RicardoJesus It is a lot of typing or copy/pasting, but you can insert in the shorter figure, a `\vphantom` of the exact command used to typeset the larger figure, as in for figure a, `\subfloat[Users collection.]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=30pt,width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \label{fig:database:subfig1}\vphantom{{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=50pt,width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \label{fig:database:subfig2}}}}`

Comment: @RicardoJesus alternately, you can insert a `\rule` in both subfigures, whose depth is slightly larger than 1/2 the biggest image (some trial/error may be needed). As in `\subfloat[Users collection.]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=30pt,width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \label{fig:database:subfig1}\rule[-27pt]{0pt}{0pt}}%
\qquad
\subfloat[Events collection.]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=50pt,width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \label{fig:database:subfig2}\rule[-27pt]{0pt}{0pt}}`

Comment: I used the \vphantom command and it worked great! Thank you very much for the in-depth examples.

Answer (score 1):

With `subcaption` package it is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{example-image}
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
\subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```